# Select listed records based on alphabet in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Am looking for some help with searching the list of records by clicking the alphabet on the top or at the bottom of the application.

I am already listing the records but since the list is huge, i would like to select the record based on the alphabet select as it will be difficult to click next for next 20 pages to get to what I want. Something like below.....

Any help appreciated!!!!

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

U can filter them in sql with `surname Like 'P%'` or in LINQ by changing where : `items.Where(r => r.Surname.StartsWith("P"))`. P is only example.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But, How can I make it display the alphabets on the top or at the bottom? The screenshot provided, I got it from somewhere else, that is not what i am working on but am looking for a solution like that in my application too.